# Place logo + change its opacity and scale + add text at random position

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 3 complex filters and can't figure how do i make it in one command to work:

1. Random text position
   `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf drawtext=\"fontsize=40:fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:fontcolor={color}:text='{watermarkText}':x=if(eq(mod(n\\,20)\\,0)\\,rand(0\\,(w-text_w))\\,x):y=if(eq(mod(n\\,20)\\,0)\\,rand(0\\,(h-text_h))\\,y)\" -c:a copy {outputFile}`
2. Logo opacity
   `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i pog.png -filter_complex "[1:v]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.1*alpha(X,Y)'[zork]; [0:v][zork]overlay" {outputFile}`
3. Logo scaling
   `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i pog.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w='iw*10/100':h='ow/mdar'[wm][vid];[vid][wm]overlay=10:10" video1.mp4`

Is it even possible to make it as one working command?

Comment: Why all these escape characters?

Comment: Because it's escaping symbols for my code... Why are you asking this?

Comment: Hello, what did you attempt to make it as one command and where did it fail?

Comment: @Destroy666 i tried multiple options, enclosed everything under quotes, changed position etc.

Comment: Then please show your attempts instead of writing "I made multiple attempts". Unless you also expect a "Yes, you can do it" type of answers.

Comment: @Destroy666 so you really need me posting here multiple nonsense errors? Just to check whether i really tried myself before asking for help?

Comment: They're not non-sense errors... They show what kind of mistake you made so that people don't repeat them. The 2nd sentence is your presumption, which now makes me indeed think you haven't tried anything.

Comment: @Destroy666 ...So you know how to make it work or not?.... Like, this stackoverflow platform is ridiculous.... You waste your time making presumptions, looking for reasons to downvote etc... but not helping. Like...

Comment: I didn't downvote you and tried to explain nicely that shown effort is required here. But now I'm downvoting since honestly you now look like one of those people that do a bunch of throwaway accounts (the name also matches that) on this network just to ask a question in a non-welcome way and achieve mostly nothing. Why use these websites if you don't agree with how they work?

Comment: Thank you, very mature. And now you get flagged. Hope that was time well-spent for you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't (generally) vetted your individual filters, only combined them.

In one:

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i pog.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w='iw*10/100':h='ow/mdar'[wm][vid];[vid]drawtext=fontsize=40:fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:fontcolor={color}:text='{watermarkText}':x=if(eq(mod(n,20),0),rand(0,(w-text_w)),x):y=if(eq(mod(n,20),0),rand(0,(h-text_h)),y)[vid];[wm]colorchannelmixer=aa=0.1[wm];[vid][wm]overlay=10:10" -c:a copy {outputFile}`

I'll leave escaping upto you.